# StackOverflow error Android/Eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout, stack-overflow, android-xml

Everytime I add ab xml layout in the res folder, an error pops up saying that a problem has occurred in logo.xml: java.lang.StackOverflowError and when I click ok, Eclipse says:

> A stack overflow error has occurred. You are recommended to exit the
> workbench. Subsequent errors may happen and may terminate the
> workbench without warning. See the .log file for more details.
>
> Do you want to exit the work bench?

I can't figure it out why. It's annoying and frustrating. How can I get fix it?

Here's logo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:contentDescription="@string/desclogo"
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:src="@drawable/application_logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

NOTE:
The error pops up everytime I add an Android XML file in the /res folder, and sometimes it pops up even just opening the xml file in the /res folder.

Comment: What is the full stack trace for the error. Also code?

Comment: When you add more items Eclipse does a build (depending on the settings). Is this error caused by the XML or is there a coding error being identified as part of the build. Might be useful to see this XML file of yours if there is any content.

Comment: What does the .log file that is specified say?

Comment: it occurs when i'm adding a new Android XML file in the project,

Comment: when i checked the Windows Menu--> Error Log it says in the Message logo.xml:java.lang.StackOverflowError and in the Plug in column it says: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt

Comment: Post logo.xml please. Probably there  is a cyclic dependency

Comment: IF not - have you got the latest ADT installed?

Comment: yes, and i'm using eclipse indigo, is it because of the eclipse version?

Answer (score 8):

Just had this problem. When it asks to close the workbench, answer no, go to the graphical view of the open XML file, and change the theme using the combobox in the top right. If that doesn't work, try playing with the other settings around it. Must be some kind of bug in the Android graphical editor.

Comment: After I had switched from 4.0.3 in that combobox to 2.3.3, it worked again.  The problem was probably that I had not installed the 4.0.3 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project.

Select **Android Tools > Add Support Libraries...**

(a progress bar will appear, and voila it should download what you need)

By the way, you should really install the latest android-sdk update. From your screenshot, it doesn't look like you have yet.

**Or you can try this too**

Make sure that the value of **android:targetSdkVersion** in AndroidManifest.xml matches **target=android-** in project.properties. If these two values are not the same, building with build tools version 19.0.0 will end in the BufferOverflowException. Source

There is also some indication from comments on this post that you need to target at least 19 (android-19). Please leave a comment if this solution also works if your target is < 19.

This is how the fix looks for my project. The related AOSP issue is #61710.

1 If you really need to downgrade, you don't need to uninstall build tools 19.0.0, simply install 18.1.1 and add sdk.buildtools=18.1.1 to the local.properties file.